# Parsing XML Always Returns Null

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing, inputstream

I have an XML file containing data I need to parse in my application however the values are continuously appearing null when I attempt to debug although I've verified I can access the XML file on the server.

I continually get this in my logcat and it causes other issues down the line in my code:

```
08-13 17:56:39.452: I/System.out(1424): STREAM DEBUG
08-13 17:56:39.452: I/System.out(1424): null
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Relevant Source Snippet:

```java
public class ConfigFinalActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    private static final String TAG = "ConfigActivity";
    TelephonyManager tm;
    AlertDialog mErrorAlert = null;
    private Notification mNotification = null;
    private Button assist_update_btn = null;
    // Progress
    private ImageView mProgressImageview1;
    private ImageView mProgressImageview2;
    private ImageView mProgressImageview3;
    private ImageView mProgressImageview4;
    private ImageView mProgressImageview5;

    private int mInstructionNumber = 0;
    UpdateActivity update;
    public ArrayList<String> ValueArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public ArrayList<String> nameArr = new ArrayList<String>(5);
    public ArrayList<String> ApnArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public ArrayList<String> mmscArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public ArrayList<String> mmsportArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public ArrayList<String> mmsproxyArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public ArrayList<String> portArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    public ArrayList<String> proxyArr = new ArrayList<String>();
    private Button mAssistInstrButton = null;
    private TextView mReadAgainButton = null;
    public static int TotalSteps = 8;
    public static int count;
    int i, g = 0;
    Context ctx;
    public static ContentValues Values = new ContentValues();
    XmlParserHandlerFinal handler;
    public static BigInteger id1, id2;
    BigInteger[] id;
    public static Integer mdn1, mdn2;
    public static String car;
    public static final Uri APN_TABLE_URI = Uri
            .parse("content://telephony/carriers");
    public static String Base_URL = "https://www.mysettings.com/";
    //NetworkTask task = new NetworkTask();
    NetworkTask tasks = new NetworkTask();
    InputStream stream = null;
    private AnimationDrawable loadingAnimation;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            int version = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
            tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            int networkType = tm.getNetworkType();
            int phoneType = tm.getPhoneType();
            tasks = new NetworkTask();
            handler = new XmlParserHandlerFinal();

            handler.setContext(ctx);
            getImpVariablesForQuery();

            if (version < VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {

            try {
                // updating layout initially has updating text with 1 dot in the
                // xml
                setContentView(R.layout.updating);
                // This image view has the updating text to be progressively
                // updated
                // with dots addition
                ImageView loading = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.loading_empty1);

                // Set updating button to drawable animation
                loading.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.updating1);
                loadingAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) loading.getBackground();

                ImageView loading2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.loading_empty2);

                // Set updating button to drawable animation
                loading2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.updating2);
                loadingAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) loading2.getBackground();

                ImageView loading3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.loading_empty3);

                // Set updating button to drawable animation
                loading.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.updating3);
                loadingAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) loading.getBackground();

                ImageView loading4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.loading_empty4);

                // Set updating button to drawable animation
                loading.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.updating4);
                loadingAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) loading.getBackground();

                ImageView loading5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.loading_empty5);

                // Set updating button to drawable animation
                loading.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.updating5);
                loadingAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) loading.getBackground();

                tasks.execute("http://datasettings.site90.net/GetPhoneSettings-ST-rsp-eng.xml");
                if (tasks.get() != null) {
                    stream = tasks.getInputStream();
                    Log.v("CfA", "here");

                } else if (tasks.get() == null) {
                    setContentView(R.layout.error);

                    // finish();
                    // finish();

                }

                handler.getQueryResponse(stream);

                Values = getContentValues();

            } catch (SAXException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Update APN table in separate thread
            new TableUpdateRequestTask().execute("");

        } else {// ICS and later versions

            tasks.execute("http://datasettings.site90.net/GetPhoneSettings-ST-rsp-eng.xml");
            System.out.println("STREAM DEBUG");
            System.out.println(stream);
            try {
                if (tasks.get() != null) {
                    stream = tasks.getInputStream();
                    Log.v("CfA", "here");

                } else if (tasks.get() == null) {
                    setContentView(R.layout.error);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            // startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APN_SETTINGS));
            try {

                System.out.println("STREAM DEBUG2");
                System.out.println(stream);

                handler.getQueryResponse(stream);
            //  System.out.println("STREAM DEBUG");
                //System.out.println(stream);
                System.out.println(nameArr);
                System.out.println(ApnArr);
                System.out.println(mmscArr);
                System.out.println(mmsproxyArr);
                System.out.println(mmsportArr);
                System.out.println(count);
                System.out.println(proxyArr);

                System.out.println(portArr);

                Values = getContentValues();
                showNotification();
            } catch (SAXException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();

                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            new TableUpdateRequestTask().execute("");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Send more details. it is not clear where is the problem

Comment: I added a snippet from my logcat if that helps - if not just let me know what other details you might want and I'll be happy to provide them : ) 

- Amani Swann

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're starting a thread and then immediately using data that is to be created on the thread?  Is that true?

If so, you need to create a handler and send messages from your thread to the handler to indicate progress or when the thread is complete.

So, all of this code would change to just tasks.execute(...) and then your thread would send a message to your handler indicating when the thread is done executing.  When your handler receives the message, you can use the information created in the thread.  [Here's a good article on this subject.](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html)

Also, yeah, don't use System.out.println in Android.  Use the [Log](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) class instead.

Comment: I have a handler (I updated my source to show it completely) did I do something wrong?